# What is the correct call for retrieving a human readable view ID when it's created programmatically?

Tags: android-layout, drag-and-drop

Sorry about the doozy of a title.

I'm trying to get the human readable ID of some views I created in code. This is done in a drag and drop bit of code.

Here is the code for setting up the views:

```
//In onCreate:
  LinearLayout s5=((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stack4));
    s5.addView(topCardbuild());
    s5.addView(faceCardbuild());
 //topcardbuild is the same, but with a different drawable passed to it. 



  public View faceCardbuild(){
    LinearLayout btnFace = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsHI = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // button margins
    paramsHI.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -60);
    //paramsLO.setMargins() left top right botton
    // button height/width *pixels*
    paramsHI.height = 96;
    paramsHI.width = 72;

    btnFace.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    ImageButton i1 = new ImageButton(this);
    i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c6);

    //getResources().getResourceEntryName("ic_launcher", "drawable", getPackageName());
    int resID;
    //resID = getResources().getResourceName("ic_launcher", "drawable", getPackageName());
    resID = getResources().getIdentifier("c6", "drawable", getPackageName());
    i1.setId(resID);

    Log.d("facecard build", "Facecard resID is " + resID + " image resource ID is " + R.drawable.c6);
    Log.d("facecard build", " converted that is " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID));
    btnFace.addView(i1, paramsHI);
    i1.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());


    return btnFace;

}
```

Those logs report the names back to me correctly. However, when I go to my drag and drop code and try to retrieve the names, it errors out and crashes. If I don't try to retrieve them, I can drag and drop with no issues.

Here is my drag and drop code:

```
       case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                //ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                //It doesn't matter if it's a viewgroup or a linear layout. Both crash.
                LinearLayout owner = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();

                Log.d("drop info", "Linear Layout owner is " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(owner.getId()));
                Log.d("drop info", "Sending card is " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId()));
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                Log.d("drop info", "container is " + getResources().getResourceEntryName((container.getId())) + " it has children " + container.getChildCount() + " before move");


                if (viewCheck(view, container)){
                    //returns true, move views
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    //returns false, don't move views
                }
                if (owner.getChildCount() < 2){
                    owner.getLayoutParams().height = 160;

                }else {
                    owner.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                }
                Log.d("drop info", " and children after move " + container.getChildCount());
                cCount = container.getChildCount() - 2;
                View temp;
                if (cCount >= 1) {
                    temp = container.getChildAt(cCount);
                    String child1;
                    child1 = getResources().getResourceName(temp.getId());
                    Log.d("drop info", "one less child is " + child1);
                    Log.d("drop info", "sending stack has children " + owner.getChildCount());
                }



                if (container.getChildCount()>= 2){
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -60);
                view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }


                if (container.getChildCount() < 2){
                    owner.getLayoutParams().height = 160;
                }else {
                    container.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                }

                break;
```

The drag and drop code works just fine for Imagebuttons(views) I have created in my XML file. It's the views I create in my code that I have issue retrieving the ID for.

This is the most extensive I've ever delved into view manipulation, so if there are glaring errors please be kind.

Edit: Here is the error I get when I try to read the IDs.
W/ResourceType﹕ No known package when getting name for resource number 0xffffffff

Every Google result indicated they either solved it themselves, or says to explicitly define the ID. As best I can tell, I've done that in faceCardbuild.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small function to simply check the names of the views, and found it was retrieving -1.

After some time spent looking at the code, I saw I was assigning i1 (The imagebutton) the setID function, but not it's parent, btnFace.

I changed it so btnFace.setID got my resID value, and it worked!

I can now retrieve the IDs for these views.